# numpy.getbuffer and numpy.frombuffer

Tags: python, numpy, buffer

I am trying to wrap my head around the numpy implementation of PEP3118.  How exactly does buffer access work in numpy.

```
>>> p = numpy.getbuffer(numpy.arange(10))
>>> p
<read-write buffer for 0x1003e5b10, size -1, offset 0 at 0x1016ab4b0>
>>> numpy.frombuffer(p)
array([  0.00000000e+000,   4.94065646e-324,   9.88131292e-324,
     1.48219694e-323,   1.97626258e-323,   2.47032823e-323,
     2.96439388e-323,   3.45845952e-323,   3.95252517e-323,
     4.44659081e-323])
```

So I am getting unexpected returns.  I would expect to see an array with 10 elements from 0-9.  I can get into the array and read/write though.

```
>>> j = numpy.frombuffer(p)
>>> j
array([  0.00000000e+000,   4.94065646e-324,   9.88131292e-324,
     1.48219694e-323,   1.97626258e-323,   2.47032823e-323,
     2.96439388e-323,   3.45845952e-323,   3.95252517e-323,
     4.44659081e-323])
>>> j += 1
>>> j
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

So it looks like the buffer is initializing to all zeros, which I can then write to.  The functionality that I am expecting is to be able to build the array (with arange or asarray) directly to the buffer with getbuffer.  Is that not possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a simple `dtype` problem. The buffer you create with

```
np.getbuffer(np.arange(10))
```

has a `dtype=int`, because `np.arange` uses `dtype=int` by default.

Then, when you try to read your buffer with

```
np.frombuffer(p)
```

you're in fact using the `dtype=float` default of `np.frombuffer`. Instead, use

```
np.frombuffer(p, dtype=int)
```

et voilà, you get

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 9):

Let me add some remarks to the excellent existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12462633/1499402) by Pierre.

You need `getbuffer` only if you have to slice an `ndarray`: you can retrieve the python buffer object associated with the whole array via the `data` attribute

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a.data == np.getbuffer(a)
True
```

On the contrary, you do not need to pass an actual buffer object to the `frombuffer` function, every object that exposes the `buffer` interface is good.

```
>>> np.frombuffer(a, a.dtype)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> np.frombuffer(a)
array([  0.00000000e+000,   4.94065646e-324,   9.88131292e-324,
         1.48219694e-323,   1.97626258e-323,   2.47032823e-323,
         2.96439388e-323,   3.45845952e-323,   3.95252517e-323,
         4.44659081e-323])
>>> import array
>>> c = array.array('i', range(10))
>>> np.frombuffer(c, np.int32)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)
>>> np.frombuffer(c)
array([  2.12199579e-314,   6.36598737e-314,   1.06099790e-313,
         1.48539705e-313,   1.90979621e-313])
```

When *decoding* a buffer object, you have to know the correct `dtype` as the examples above demonstrate. To be more precise, buffer objects do not have a `dtype`: they are just a stream of binary data. Instead `ndarray` objects have a `dtype` that dictates how the underlying binary data is interpreted.

To answer your question: every numpy `ndarray` exposes the buffer interface. You can access the buffer or a slice of it via the `data` descriptor or the `getbuffer` function. You can create `ndarray`'s from object exposing the buffer interface by means of the `frombuffer` function. Since buffer (as opposed to `ndarrays`) do not have `dtype` information, you should always explicitly specify how the buffer has to be interepreted via the `dtype` argument to `frombuffer`.

Comment: What a wonderful addendum to Pierre's answer.  The additional detail is quite appreciated.